# How to find using javascript the maximum users browser window width and current

Tags: javascript

I am searching a way using javascript to find visitors browser window width and height but i want also find the maximum window sizes so if the user make the window smaller or bigger some elements change automatic position or size like facebook chat. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you considered using relative positioning and setting width and height based on percentage?

Comment: The maximum window size is not necessarily constrained by the physical dimensions of a user's screen. Nor will a user necessarily want a window that is as large as their maximum screen size. Consider a user with a desktop extended over two screens. It is unlikely (but possible) that they want a window over both screens. Just deal with the window you have, and use CSS, not javascript.

Answer (score 12):

The maximum browser size width would be the width and height of the screen:

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

But I'd use CSS media queries for what you're trying to do:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Something like this would make the page background black if the window is less than 500px wide:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

Update:

Oh, and you'll want a polyfill for older browsers that don't support media queries:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

That'll get you media queries all the way down through IE6!

Comment: +1 never knew about the ability to use things like max-width with media queries in css.

Comment: Please do accept if it answered your question. I'm quite the karma whore. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Maximum window height is

```
window.screen.availHeight - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.innerWidth` and  `window.innerHeight`

You can position any dom element relative to window using css position 'fixed' or absolute so that on window resize the will readjust itself.

You can use `window.onresize` to listen window resize event

jQuery equivalent

`$(window).width(); $(window).height()` and `$(window).resize(function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, it's pretty easy to set up a listener in a cross-browser fashion:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  alert($(window).width()) //window width
  alert($(window).height()) //window height
}).trigger("resize") //to ensure that you do whatever you're going to do when the window is first loaded;
```